# Ignoring file 'google.list’' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

Tags: apt, software-sources

when i do "sudo apt-get update" following output is generated at the end:-

```
N: Ignoring file 'google.list’' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

Any solution for this????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list’ /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
```

I thinks this should work as the file currently has the name `google.list’`, but it needs to end in `*.list` to work - the above command should move/rename it to  a file with the appropriate extension.

Comment: Thanx a lot.. it works.. :)