# Mariadb-server and mariadb-client

Tags: apt, dependencies, mariadb

I have ben trying to install mariadb-server and mariadb-client on my ubuntu 18.04 VPS, but when I run apt install -y mariadb-server mariadb-client it returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-client : Depends: mariadb-client-10.8 (>= 1:10.8.3+maria~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.8 (>= 1:10.8.3+maria~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
N: Ignoring file 'mariadb.list.old_3' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'mariadb.list.old_2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'mariadb.list.old_1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have been looking for more than 2 hours and couldn't find any solution that works.

Can someone help, please?

Thx!

Comment: `you have requested an impossible situation` and `you have held broken packages` suggest that you have added one or more non-Ubuntu or wrong-version sources, then unwisely installed conflicting software from that source(s). You must uninstall those conflicting packages, then stop using those sources. If you're looking for single magic incantation, there isn't one; the problem must be *understood*, then it's easily cured.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignoring file 'google.list’' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499890/ignoring-file-google-list-in-directory-etc-apt-sources-list-d-as-it-has-a)